# Jquery fadeOut issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fadeout

this is just a test to increase my knowledge of Jquery can someone please tell me why when I hover over the #box5 object it Shows the white and blue box more than once.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Box5").hide();
    $("#Button").click(function () {
    $("#Button").val("Show");
    $("#BoxArea").toggle();
    $("#Box5").toggle();
});
$("#Box5").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $(this).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        $(this).show(100);
        $(this).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            $(this).show(100);
            $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                $(this).show(100);
            });
         });
      });
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45X2L/3/

Comment: A jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Just forgot to add it in

Comment: Because the default `fadeOut` duration is 400ms, but you call `show` with a 100? just a guess

Comment: nope I've messed about with the fadeOut duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.
>
> See the discussions for [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) for more details.

Change the event to `mouseenter` and it will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Box5").hide();
    $("#Button").click(function () {
        $("#Button").val("Show");
        $("#BoxArea").toggle();
        $("#Box5").toggle();
    });
    $("#Box5").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
        $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            $(this).show(400);

            $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "white");
                $(this).show(400);

                $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    $(this).show(400);

                });
            });

        });
    });


});
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain why only the last two are triggered more than once?

Answer (score -1):

I think what's happening is that when you fadeOut `#Box5` call `$(this).show()` and show it, it gets displayed right under the mouse pointer, triggering another `hover` event since the animation leads the box to have the pointer enter its area.

Adding an `alert` at the beginning of the hover handler will let you see what I mean.

I think the only way to solve this would be to switch the hover handler off when doing the fadeOut/fadeIn stuff and then switching it back on when finished.